# What is colour-Coulomb interaction?

Tags: coulombs-law, interactions, strong-force

In several publications (e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06864) a "colour Coulomb interaction" between quarks was mentioned. What kind of interaction is that, is it electromagnetic or strong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour Coulomb interaction is another name for the one-gluon exchange potential between (typically heavy) quarks or other sources having colour. It is a straightforward generalisation of the Abelian (i.e. standard) Coulomb potential stemming from one-photon exchange,

$$ V(r) = -\alpha/r \; ,$$

where $r$ is the distance between the sources taken to be elementary charges $\pm e$ for simplicity. In this case the potential strength is just the fine structure constant, $\alpha = e^2/4\pi = 1/137$ (in natural units, $\hbar = 1 = c$). Note that $1/r$ is basically the Fourier transform of the photon propagator

$$ \left. \frac{1}{q^2} \right|_{q^0 = 0} = - \frac{1}{\mathbf{q}^2} \; , $$

at zero energy transfer, $q^0 = 0$, corresponding to the static approximation.

To obtain the non-Abelian generalisation one just replaces

$$ \alpha \to C_2(R) \, \alpha_s \; , $$

where $\alpha_s$ is the strong interaction coupling and $C_2(R) = T^a(R) T^a(R)$ the quadratic Casimir in the representation $R$ of colour SU(3). For quarks, $R = F = [3]$, the fundamental representation and $C_2(F) = 4/3$. For octet sources such as gluons, $R = A = [8]$, the adjoint representation, and $C_2(A) = 3$.

NB: For SU(N), the Casimir operators are $C_2([N]) = (N^2-1)/2N$ and $C_2([N^2-1]) = N$, see e.g. Peskin and Schroeder, Ch. 15.4.

The fact that the non-Abelian potential is proportional to $C_2(R)$ is widely believed to hold beyond perturbation theory, i.e. also for the string tensions in different representations. This conjecture goes under the name of Casimir scaling, see e.g. Jeff Greensite's [review on confinement](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0301023).